# Convert a text CSV binary file and get a random line from it in Python without reading it to memory

Tags: python, csv, numpy, bigdata, random-access

I have some CSV text files in the format:

```
1.3, 0, 1.0
20.0, 3.2, 0
30.5, 5.0, 5.2
```

The files are about 3.5Gb in size and I cannot read any of them in to memory in Pandas in a useful amount of time.

But I don't need to read the all file, because what I want to do, is to choose some random lines from the file and read the values there, and I know it's theoretically possible to do it if the file is formatted in a way that all the fields have the same size - for instance, float16 in a binary file.

Now, I think I can just convert it, using the NumPy method specified in the answer to question:
[How to output list of floats to a binary file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807863/how-to-output-list-of-floats-to-a-binary-file-in-python)

**But, how do I go about picking a random line from it after the conversion is done?**

In a normal text file, I could just do:

```
import random
offset = random.randrange(filesize)
f = open('really_big_file')
f.seek(offset)                  #go to random position
f.readline()                    # discard - bound to be partial line
random_line = f.readline()      # bingo!
```

But I can't find a way for this to work in a binary file made from NumPy.

Comment: @TimPietzcker -- Isn't that basically what the code snippet is doing?  Of course, with that approach you eliminate the possibility of picking the first line ...

Comment: No, because the lines in the original text CSV, have different length, and as such I would get a bias that would favour the bigger lines to get picked instead of the smaller ones. (i.e., in the example data, the 3rd line would have almost a 30% higher probability of being chosen than the 1st.)

Comment: @jbssm -- Hmm... Interesting point.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `struct` to convert to binary:

```
import struct
with open('input.txt') as fin, open('output.txt','wb') as fout:
     for line in fin:
         #You could also use `csv` if you're not lazy like me ...
         out_line = struct.pack('3f',*(float(x) for x in line.split(',')))
         fout.write(out_line)
```

This writes everything as standard 4-byte floats on most systems.

Now, to read the data again:

```
with open('output.txt','rb') as fin:
    line_size = 12 #each line is 12 bytes long (3 floats, 4 bytes each)
    offset = random.randrange(filesize//line_size)  #pick n'th line randomly
    f.seek(offset*line_size) #seek to position of n'th line
    three_floats_bytes = f.read(line_size)
    three_floats = struct.unpack('3f',three_floats_bytes)
```

If you're concerned about disk space and want to compress the data down using `np.float16` (2 byte floats), you can do that too using the basic skeleton above, just substitute `np.fromstring` for `struct.unpack` and `ndarray.tostring` in place of `struct.pack` (with the appropriate data-type ndarray of course -- and `line_size` would drop to 6 ...).

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. By combining your example with the one I mentioned in the question about NumPy, I was able to do what I wanted in NumPy. I think I'll add it below.

Comment: Just to say that this code doesn't work. I get the error: lineOut = struct.pack('3f', *(float(x) for x in line.split(',')))
struct.error: pack requires exactly 3 arguments

Comment: @jbssm -- Then it looks like you have a record with more (or less) than 3 elements in it.

Comment: I checked what is wrong. I have like 10 elements, so I use something like out_line = struct.pack('10f',*(float(x) for x in line.split(','))) instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to play around with offsets depending on storage size, but:

```
import csv
import struct
import random

count = 0
with open('input.csv') as fin, open('input.dat', 'wb') as fout:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    for row in csvin:
        for col in map(float, row):
            fout.write(struct.pack('f', col))
            count += 1


with open('input.dat', 'rb') as fin:
    i = random.randrange(count)
    fin.seek(i * 4)
    print struct.unpack('f', fin.read(4))
```

Comment: This seeks to a random float, not a random line of floats.  In other words, you're losing your "record" information here.

Comment: @mgilson indeed - I just saw your answer - but it's pretty much the same, just adjust the `line_size` as you've called it

Answer (score 0):

So, using the example provided by the helpfull answers, I found a way to do it with NumPy if someone is interested:

```
# this converts the file from text CSV to bin
with zipfile.ZipFile("input.zip", 'r') as inputZipFile:
    inputCSVFile = inputZipFile.open(inputZipFile.namelist()[0], 'r') # it's 1 file only zip

    with open("output.bin", 'wb') as outFile:
        outCSVFile = csv.writer(outFile, dialect='excel')
        for line in inputCSVFile:
            lineParsed = ast.literal_eval(line)
            lineOut = numpy.array(lineParsed,'float16')
            lineOut.tofile(outFile)
        outFile.close()

    inputCSVFile.close()
    inputZipFile.close()

# this reads random lines from the binary file
with open("output.bin", 'wb') as file:
    file.seek(0)

    lineSize = 20 # float16 has 2 bytes and there are 10 values:
    fileSize = os.path.getsize("output.bin")

    offset = random.randrange(fileSize//lineSize)
    file.seek(offset * lineSize)
    random_line = file.read(lineSize)
    randomArr = numpy.fromstring(random_line, dtype='float16')
```