# Writing binary files in python to be read by C

Tags: python, c, binary

I have to use a program written in C that read data from a binary file in this way

```
nCnt = 0;
for (i=0;i<h.nsph;++i) {
    fread(&gp,sizeof(struct gas_particle),1,fp);
    if (bGas) {
        kd->p[nCnt].iOrder = nCnt;
        for (j=0;j<3;++j) kd->p[nCnt].r[j] = gp.pos[j];
        ++nCnt;
        }

    }
```

The above code is not the whole code of the program I'm using but only the part relevant for my question. I need to read the positions of `nCnt` particles, i.e. the coordinate for each particle.
I have these positions in a python array, which looks like this

```
 pos=array([[[ 0.4786236 ,  0.49046784,  0.48877147],
    [ 0.47862025,  0.49042325,  0.48877267],
    [ 0.47862737,  0.49039413,  0.4887735 ],
    ..., 
    [ 0.4785084 ,  0.49032556,  0.48860968],
    [ 0.47849332,  0.49041115,  0.48877266],
    [ 0.47849161,  0.49041022,  0.48877176]]])
```

How should I write this array in a binary file so that the C code would read it fine?

Comment: Presumably that is a `numpy` array?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807863/how-to-output-list-of-floats-to-a-binary-file-in-python (proposed solution uses http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html)?

Comment: Don't you want to stringify your data for universality? For example you can store it in JSON, in that case you won't depend on endianness or bitness.

Comment: You should show the declaration of the `struct gas_particle`. Also, `fread()` (like all I/O) can fail, the return value should be checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the python module `array` and it's [tofile() method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#array.array.tofile) to write the data in a format which C can read or the [IO routines if you use numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html).

With the number of digits, the `'f'` format (float) should work.

In C, you can read each line like so:

```
float values[3];
fread( values, sizeof( float ), 3, fh );
```

Comment: @unwind: What specifically isn't C?

Comment: It's better now, the strange declaration of `values` has been fixed. Still, it's missing an argument to `fread()` and the arguments that are present are given in the wrong order.

Comment: Why does the answer include any C at all though?  The OP said he has to use a C program that was already written.

Comment: @JohnY: Ah, I somehow missed that.

Comment: Removed my downvote now that the `fread()` call at least would build. :)