# Write ndarray as binary and read with correct shape

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, binaryfiles

I have an `N` by `6` by `f` numpy array. I would like to be able to write this as a binary file and then read it by another python script into an array of the same dimensions.

To test this, I do the following [(based on this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807863/how-to-output-list-of-floats-to-a-binary-file-in-python):

```
import numpy as np

farray=np.array([[3.14, 2.7, 0.0, -1.0, 1.1],[3.14, 2.7, 0.0, -1.0, 1.1]])
testf = open('test','wb')
farray.tofile(testf)
testf.close()

arraytest = np.fromfile('test')
```

At which point `arraytest.shape` is `(10,)`. How can I make sure it is `(2,5)` instead **without having to know 2 and 5 in advance to reshape the array**? Can I somehow encode this information in the binary file as you would do with `\n` in a regular text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use np.save & np.load?

```
import numpy as np
farray=np.array([[3.14, 2.7, 0.0, -1.0, 1.1],[3.14, 2.7, 0.0, -1.0, 1.1]])
np.save('nums.npy', farray)
loaded_farray = np.load('nums.npy')
print(loaded_farray)
```

[[ 3.14  2.7   0.   -1.    1.1 ]
 [ 3.14  2.7   0.   -1.    1.1 ]]